# Statistical analysis and prediction of variations in anatomical features

Tags: predictive-models

I am doing a statistical analysis of variations in anatomical features, for example the shape of a pelvis bone. I found out that morphometric method can be used to quantify differences in geometry (e.g. shape and texture). My question is, what kind of method can I use to predict the shape variation of an anatomical feature based on a limited observation?
Reference:
[1. Predictive Properties of Statistical Shape Models](http://www.hartung-gorre.de/vision67.htm)
[2. Prediction of biomechanical parameters of the proximal femur using statistical appearance models and support vector regression.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18979792am)

Comment: What is the amount of data you have? I'm assuming you have a decent amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible method is SVM (Support vector Machines), it needs a decent amount of data to train the model. The classifier function constructed during the training completely decides the differences in data between the classes. Similar kind of study is [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2768070/)

We can do this using SAS/R/Python

Hope this helps !